# Regarding extracting GA-4 data with api in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets-api, google-workspace

While extracting data through addon api in google sheets or even if I try to extract data of GA4 through looker studio.

I see transaction id's getting clubbed as others. So,for eg I extracted data of oct from 1st to 23rd oct on 23th oct, I see transaction id getting clubbed from 17th oct to 22nd oct.

Transaction ID  Date    Session source / medium Transactions    Purchase revenue
(other) 10/17/2023  (other) 186 372789
(other) 10/18/2023  (other) 256 439604
(other) 10/19/2023  (other) 302 504959.9
(other) 10/20/2023  (other) 270 440782.7
(other) 10/21/2023  (other) 421 667452.8
(other) 10/22/2023  (other) 710 1195155

But when I extract data on 23rd oct for 1st to 23rd oct, I see 17th oct data getting updated with all transaction id and transaction id getting clubbed from 18th to 23rd oct.

The point i am trying to make here is that If I am extracting GA4 data 25th oct, I see from 18th to 24th oct data having clubbed transaction id and next when I extract the same data that is on 26th, it gets
updated for 18th oct with all traction id and from 19th oct to 25th oct transaction id gets clubbed.

Transaction ID  Date    Session source / medium Transactions    Purchase revenue
(other) 10/18/2023  (other) 256 439604
(other) 10/19/2023  (other) 302 504959.9
(other) 10/20/2023  (other) 270 440782.7
(other) 10/21/2023  (other) 421 667452.8
(other) 10/22/2023  (other) 710 1195155
(other) 10/23/2023  (other) 658 1073808

The above problem is coming from all the google sheets api's that helps data to extract from GA4 and even in looker studio.
But if I see same data in GA-4 portal in explore section, I see the correct data.

**Looker studio**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4T9X0.png)

**GA4 portal
**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Caf4K.png)

Please help me on this and let me know if we can connect on this via google meeting.

Regards,
Saransh